# Understanding XOR (Exclusive Or) in code

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, xor

I understand the idea and concept of XOR outside of code. But I wanted an easy explanation when it's used in code. Let me give you a few examples of what I'm having trouble understanding.

Say we wanted to Swap internet values in C++ with out using a third temp variable and by using XOR, like so:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;

int *x = &a;
int *y = &b;

*x ^= *y;
*y ^= *x;
*x ^= *y;
```

Now I understand that `*x ^= y` translates to `*x = *x ^ *y` But I just need to understand one line only to understand the rest. Basically, in `*x = *x ^ *y` why is *y always being set to *x in order to being the swap sequence? (Or am I getting that part wrong too?) How is *y being exclusively chosen and on what criteria?

Comment: Your example is faulty: ^ = is not ^= operator.  Also, int *x=&a and int *y=&b;

Comment: That is the [XOR swap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). Try writing out the bit sequences before and after that line if you don't follow it.

Comment: _"Say we wanted to Swap internet values ..."_ Are you talking about network byte oder actually?

Comment: unrelated, but `int *x = a` is wrong, you want `int *x = &a`. Also, XOR swapping is a trick that one shouldn't use, the compiler optimize better that most of us. Also, the XOR swapping doesn't work whenever `x` and `y` point to the same object.

Comment: You could also use add and subtract, to swap two integers a and b: | a = a + b; | b = a - b; | a = a - b; | .